# Why i can't use fancy index at same time for row and column

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, row

Why i can't use fancy index at same time for row and column

i have this array:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
      [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
      [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
      [13, 14, 15, 16]])
```

code:

```
example[1:3,[1,2]]
```

result:

```
array([[ 5,  6],
      [ 9, 10]])
```

this is okey but when i try

code:

```
example[[1,2],[1,2]]
```

result:

```
array([ 5, 10])
```

Isn't same things 1:3 and [1,2] why i can't see 1 and 2 indexed columns again.
Why aren't results same?

Comment: Your question is not understandable what exactly you want